# Python Pandas Multiindexing select rows that match all values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Consider the following data frame.

```
import Pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Folder'] = [2,3,4,5  ,2,4,5, 2,3,4, 2,3,4,5,1]
df['Country'] = ['USA','USA','USA','USA'  ,'Mexico','Mexico','Mexico', 'UK','UK','UK', 'Canada','Canada','Canada','Canada','Canada']
df['Data'] = [20,30,43,15  ,25,44,15, 26,37,47, 24,34,47,55,18]
df.set_index(['Country','Folder'], drop=True, inplace=True)
df


                Data
Country Folder      
USA     2         20
        3         30
        4         43
        5         15
Mexico  2         25
        4         44
        5         15
UK      2         26
        3         37
        4         47
Canada  2         24
        3         34
        4         47
        5         55
        1         18
```

How do I collect the rows where Folder has all of lst=[1,3,4] in level Folder?

```
                Data
Country Folder      

Canada  2         24
        3         34
        4         47
        5         55
        1         18
```

OR

```
                Data
Country Folder      
Canada  3         34
        4         47
        1         18
```

Either would work for me. I want to know that Canada matches all of lst.  lst may be up to 8 items long.

I have tried df.query("Folder in @lst") however that returns rows matching any of lst.  I need matching All of lst.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative to @jezrael's approach, where we group on the boolean values from `isin` and country:

```
In [38]: (df.groupby([df.index.isin([1,3,4], level='Folder'),
                      df.index.get_level_values('Country')])
            .filter(lambda x: len(x)==3)
           )
Out[38]: 
                Data
Country Folder      
Canada  3         34
        4         47
        1         18
```

Take advantage of the fact that you have three numbers in the list, so if it matches all, then it should be 3.

To get all values, you could chunk the steps:

```
mapping = df.index.isin([1,3,4], level = 'Folder')

filtered = (pd.Series(mapping)
            .groupby(df.index.get_level_values('Country'))
            .transform(lambda x: sum(x)>=3)
            )

In [61]: df.loc[filtered.array]
Out[61]: 
                Data
Country Folder      
Canada  2         24
        3         34
        4         47
        5         55
        1         18
```

Comment: This works for the example, but my more complex dataset is giving an unexpected result. When none of the rows match lst and the length is 3 also seems to be valid. Working on it now. Marking as answered for the example given.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) witt convert values to sets and using `issubset` get all groups with all values in `Folder` by `lst`:

```
lst=[1,3,4]

f = lambda x: set(lst).issubset(set(x.index.get_level_values('Folder')))
mask = df.groupby('Country')['Data'].transform(f)

df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
                Data
Country Folder      
Canada  2         24
        3         34
        4         47
        5         55
        1         18
```

Last if need only matched values:

```
 df2 = df1[df1.index.isin(lst)]
```

Comment: for the last part, you could just do ``df.index.isin([1,3,4], level=1)`` to get the booleans before indexing

Comment: @sammywemmy - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in pandas 1.0.4. Which pandas version do you use?

```
df.query('Country == "Canada" and Folder in [1,3,4]')
```

or

```
l = [1,3,4]
c = 'Canada'
df.query('Country == @c and Folder in @l')
>>>
                Data
Country Folder      
Canada  3         34
        4         47
        1         18
```

Comment: This actually requires you to type in the country name. I think the OP's goal is to get the country based oncomplete matches in `lst`, without specifically specifying the country name.

Comment: Oh. If you are right, then my solution is not complete.